# adding apostrophe while checking email address

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression. I want to allow an apostrophe (') to be allowed while validating email address. I have a regular expression as one given below:

```
 private static Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
         @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" + 
         @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")
```

What changes should i have to do in the above regex to  allow (')?

Comment: Your regex fails to allow many valid email addresses, and permitting apostrophe will additionally cause it to allow invalid addresses. Why on Earth would you be doing this?

Comment: Emails with an apostrophe before the @ are valid. That's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9\'_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
         @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" + 
         @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")
```