# Allow apostrophe in multiple email id field

Tags: jquery, email-validation

I have a email field in my form. User can enter more than one email id on same time like the below format

```
test1@test.com,test2@test.com
test1@test.com, test2@test.com
test1@test.com;test2@test.com
test1@test.com; test2@test.com
```

I did this.

Now I want to allow `aj’’joy@css.com, ab’’coy@css.com,` these kind of mail id also. I tried but i am not able to  find how to allow apostrophe in email validation. Anyone can help me?

fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/8/

Comment: It looks like you've already done this from your fiddle...

Comment: No now my fiddle is not allow aj’’joy@css.com, ab’’coy@css.com

Comment: That's because those characters aren't apostrophes, they're weird floating comma things. Nobody is going to enter those. Use actual apostrophes and your current regex is fine: `aj''joy@css.com, ab''coy@css.com`

Comment: Really thanks Ant. I am an idiot i copied that email format from word document so actual apostrophes came in ’’ this format. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem - I've dropped that comment in as an answer since it seems like that was the real issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since my comment answered your question...

That's because those characters aren't apostrophes, they're weird floating comma things. Nobody is going to enter those. Use actual apostrophes and your current regex is fine:

```
aj''joy@css.com, ab''coy@css.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The updated jsfilddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/9/

I added apostrophe in

```
var email_reg = "[A-Za-z0-9\._%-']+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
```

Now working fine

Answer (score 0):

How about you string replace the apostrophe's first and then validate? That way you can keep using standard validators.
Just out of curiosity - why would you want to do this? Kindof defeats the purpose of 'validating' the e-mail address. Since an e-mail address with an apostrophe is not valid...

Comment: Hi spike my clicent requirement is email field should allow aj’’joy@css.com, ab’’coy@css.com this format

Comment: Amazin - ok, so how about my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not fully tested, but you could try

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\'_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

As a starting point.

See this c# answer [adding apostrophe while checking email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189707/adding-apostrophe-while-checking-email-address) for reference. Should work fine in JavaScript.

If you paste this into http://scriptular.com/ it matches emails with apostrophe's